# how to write package for sublimeREPL

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, sublimerepl

The [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) plugin for ST supports lots of languages, but not all of them. It also supports writing your own configuration file for any non-default languages. Once you've written this configuration, is there any way to include it in a regular Sublime Text plugin so that when installed along with SublimeREPL it will work and support the desired language?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking. Are you trying to include a `Main.sublime-menu` file written for SublimeREPL along with a totally separate plugin, so that when a user installs your plugin, a menu item for your REPL will show up?

Comment: @MattDMo yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out not to be so bad. What I wanted was to be able to distribute files in a package that would work with SublimeREPL without the user moving the files. All of the tutorials I found involved having the user place command and menu files in the SublimeREPL package directory.

Sublime Text doesn't care where it finds configuration files; they're all loaded no matter where in the packages directory they are found. `Main.sublime-menu` adds to the main menu and `*.sublime-commands` add commands.

First, fill in and rename [`Main.sublime-menu.template`](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/blob/master/config/Main.sublime-menu.template). Then do a `Default.sublime-commands` as well (couldn't find a template):

```
[
    {
        "caption": "SublimeREPL: XYZ Console",
        "command": "run_existing_window_command", "args":
        {
            "id": "repl_xyz",
            "file": "../XYZ-package/Main.sublime-menu"
        }
    }
]
```

The thing that was confusing me was how to refer to the menu file from the commands file, but it's simple; SublimeREPL uses the SublimeREPL as the working directory, so simply make a path from there to the menu file in your own package: `../XYZ-package/Main.sublime-menu`.

Add these completed files to your package and they will work just fine with SublimeREPL.